# how can i connect arduino uno to rasberry pi 3 using usb cable as serial port in windows iot using c#

Tags: c#, arduino, raspberry-pi, serial-port, windows-iot-core-10

```
using System;
using System.IO.Ports;
namespace sampleserialport
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames(); 
            Console.WriteLine("The following serial ports were found:");  
            // Display each port name to the console.      
            foreach(string port in ports) 
            {        
                Console.WriteLine(port);     
            }         
            Console.ReadLine();   
        }  
    }
}
```

this is the code am using but am getting an error at line

```
string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
```

as

> System.PlatformNotSupportedException: 'Enumeration of serial port
>   names is not supported on the current platform.'

Comment: In the Arduino GUI navigate to Tools -> Port and ensure you have setup correctly

Comment: `'Enumeration of serial port names is not supported on the current platform.'`

Answer (score 0):

APIs in System.IO.Ports namespace can not work on Windows IoT Core.  CP2102 USB 2.0 to TTL Module Serial Converter is listed in [Hardware compatibility list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/learn-about-hardware/hardwarecompatlist), and you can refer to the sample code [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-iotcore-samples/tree/master/Samples/SerialUART).